# Large scale raycasting and counting hits

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, raycasting

Firstly, I'm new to WebGL, OpenGL programming in general.  I think that these tools will allow me to solve a problem, but I don't really know where to start.

My problem:
Given a single origin, a target (triangle or mesh) and a list of many (thousands) of direction vectors, is there a way to use my GPU to count the number of rays that hit the target?  Ideally I would like to use the power of my GPU to solve this problem, as it seems better suited to it than my CPU.

I am fairly sure I could write some code to do this using my cpu, but it would take quiet a long time to go through my vectors in a for loop.

Thanks

Comment: Are the direction vectors of your rays randomly distributed or do they form a uniform grid of some sort? How many triangles do you have compared to the number of rays?

Comment: The directions are as random as possible but restricted to one hemisphere. In general I will be dealing with a simple target with less than a dozen triangles. In some cases there would be a need to look at 3 or 4 separate targets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, this is not a begginers thing though:

1. Store your triangle/mesh in VBO, this is the easy part.
2. Store your direction vectors in a texture, easy too.
3. Use *Instanced Rendering*. This way each shader instance has a different identifier.
4. Use that identifier to sample from the texture. You have a different direction vector for each shader instance.
5. Now the tricky part: The shader increments a value (the already calculated number of hits) in some buffer. Use an *image*. Read at
   [wiki Image Load Store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) about
   them, specially the "Atomic operations" part.
6. Finally, use other shader to read the value from that image.

Comment: Definitely beyond my ability now, but at least it's a starting point. I can now research the concepts and hopefully figure it out. Previously didn't even know what terms to include in my searches.

Answer (score 0):

A way I see to achieve what you are attemping to do, is to think your problem in another way, in a kind of "reversed" raycast from screen.

You say you have only one origin, a target, and *many* directions. So it is roughly like a raytracing rendering, so you can think the problem in a point of view of what WebGL is made for: drawing 3D objects on screen, using a projection matrix.

- Create a projection matrix corresponding to your origin as point of view, looking at your target, with the appropriate FOV
- Render the object in flat color (white on black background for example) in a texture, usuing this projection matrix.
- Use the same projection matrix to "project" your ray into the 2D texture coordinates.
- Check at texture pixel in the resulting 2D coordinate of the ray direction : if pixel is white, this ray hit the object.

You even can use another shader to achieve the last two parts, by passing your ray directions in a vertex buffer, with the previously created texture in the fragment shader. the probleme will be to get the incremented value from shader.